# Custom filter pipe failing Karma/Jasmine test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a custom filter pipe that works perfectly fine for filtering data in my table, however when I run tests on this pipe, the tests all fail. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null." File is the data property I pass in as parameter in transform. How do get this pipe to pass my test?

table.component.spec

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { FiltersPipe } from "./filter.pipe";

import { DataTableComponent } from "./data-table.component";

describe("DataTableComponent", () => {
  let component: DataTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DataTableComponent>;
  let filter: FiltersPipe;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [FormsModule],
        declarations: [DataTableComponent, FiltersPipe]
      }).compileComponents();

      filter = new FiltersPipe();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("filter pipe should be instanciated", () => {
    expect(FiltersPipe).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("filter pipe should return items if no field is given", () => {
    let items = [];
    items.push({ id: 1, file: "xxxx.zip" });

    let filtered = filter.transform(items, null, "file");
    expect(filtered).toEqual(items);
  });

  it("filter pipe should filter", () => {
    let items = [];

    items.push({ id: 1, file: "xxxx.zip" });
    items.push({ id: 2, file: "xxxx.zip" });
    items.push({ id: 2, file: "xxxx.zip" });
    items.push({ id: 3, file: "xxxx.zip" });

    let filtered = filter.transform(items, 2, "id");

    expect(filtered.length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

filter.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filters",
  pure: false
})
export class FiltersPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any, fields: any, selectedInput: any): any {
    if (!data) return;

    return data.filter(row => {
      if (
        row[selectedInput] !== null &&
        row[selectedInput] &&
        fields[selectedInput]
      ) {
        return row[selectedInput]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(fields[selectedInput].toString().toLowerCase());
      }
      return true;
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### filter.pipe.ts (relevant parts)

Your pipe's transform method has the signature `transform(data: any, fields: any, selectedInput: any)`, which at some point calls:

```js
if (row[selectedInput] !== null && row[selectedInput] && fields[selectedInput])
```

and

```js
.includes(fields[selectedInput].toString().toLowerCase());
```

#### third test case

In your third test case, you call the transform method as follows:

```js
filter.transform(items, null, "file")
```

Hence, `fields[selectedInput]` is `null["file"]` which leads to the error. You need to make sure, that `fields` is not undefined before you call `fields[selectedInput]`.

#### fourth test case

```js
filter.transform(items, 2, "id");
```

Then in your pipe's `transform`:
`fields[selectedInput].toString()` becomes `2["id"].toString()` which is `undefined.toString()`. => Error because you cannot call a method on `undefined`.

I am not sure, what exactly you want to achieve with your pipe but I think you mixed up your logic a bit. I'd assume, you want to check for each `item` of `items`, that `item[field] === selectedInput` (or just `startsWith` etc.)